# Can i create a rewrite in Charles Proxy so there is no response given

Tags: charles-proxy

I want to fake the response to a call by having no response at all, instead of whatever the target is returning. (as if the IP i was calling to does not exist at all). Is this possible using Charles Proxy?

Answer (score 0):

You can use rewrite and change status of the response from 200 to 404.